# Почему IE<9 и Safari для Windows не реагируют на media queries?

Tags: css3, windows, internet-explorer, safari

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, кто знает, почему браузеры `IE<9`, `Safari` версий `3.2.3 Windows 7` и `3.1.2 XP` не реагируют на медиазапросы? Есть ли способ заставить их работать с медиазапросами? Почему не работает такой способ как `css3-mediaqueries.j`s?

Comment: CSS в студию! Плюс должен быть IE9+.
У меня сейчас вообще сафари 6. Вы из века динозавров сафари достали, когда еще и css толком развит не был?..

Comment: Не пойму, зачем вам css? Ладно с Сафари, но почему на старых эксплорерах не работает такая штука, как css3-mediaqueries.js? Вообще, есть какой-либо кроссбраузерный способ применять медиазапросы или нет?

Comment: В более старых версия IE просто такого не было реализовано.
И по поводу кроссбраузерности - нет такого способа. На сейчас, на сколько я знаю, CSS3 Media Queries, официально не стало рекомендациями, а пока что еще только "кандидат". Поэтому браузеры все делают как-то по-своему. А про css3-mediaqueries.js я не слышал. Может они и сделали как-то кроссбраузерно. Но к старым версиям даже того же сафари оперы и мозиллы, это неприменимо. Эти браузеры начали реализовывать медиазапросы по новым стандартам начиная с какой-то определенной версии.